# Using Swift's .hash for password storing/checking

Tags: ios, swift, hash

**EDIT**

I've been doing more research on this topic and the answers down below have been VERY helpful! But I also just wanted to add this to anyone who might come across this page who, like me, is still struggling to understand how to install authentication into your app. (Of course, OAuth and Local authentication are very good routes, but if for some reason you can't do that, take a look at the link:)

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side

---

My original question is below

I'm VERY new to the app security part of iOS development. I have an app that should be password locked and I wanted to see the best way to secure it. So here's what I was thinking:

1. the user creates (or is provided with) a password

   ```
    let password = "password"
   ```
2. I use the .hash of that password to store it in a server
3. When and if the user needs to sign back in, they type in the password, and the app pulls down the hash number from the server and checks it against the .hash of what they just typed in

   ```
    let passwordString = textbook.text

    if passwordString.hash == hashPulledFromServer {
        //log in
    } else {
        //failed
    }
   ```

Is this the best way to do this? I've read that hashValue doesn't always produce the same value which of course wouldn't make it possible for this sense. But is this a secure way to transfer data to a server and use it to check on a password at a later date?

Comment: No, in a client-server application the client never does the password checking, that is the servers job, as is the logging in. And the server does the salting and hashing, not the client. In client-server and in client-only apps you need to decide wether you want the password to have any effect on the stored data, e.g. wether or not data should be encrypted with a key derived from the password.

Comment: It will be creating the problem. If your is also available for android and web app.

Comment: @luk2302 okay, so is it then better to use a snippet like this: func MD5(string: String) -> String {
    let digest = Insecure.MD5.hash(data: string.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data())

    return digest.map {
        String(format: "%02hhx", $0)
    }.joined()
}.  To create a hash, store it in a SQL table and let a PHP script do the work?

Comment: No, hashing in the client does not make any sense, at that point the hash becomes the password, hashing with MD5 is bad in general and hashing without a salt is even worse. You need to send the username and the password to the server which then does the salting (and peppering), hashing and storing.

Comment: *I'm VERY new to the app security part of iOS development* and *...here's what I was thinking* are two phrases that spell trouble when they appear in the same paragraph. You've got the right sort of idea, but the devil is in the details. You want a system that's been vetted by experts and proven reliable, and that rules out anything you cook up yourself. Use an existing solution.

Comment: @Caleb lol yeah that's why I wanted to ask! This was all done in a Playground, but it just didn't feel right which is why I came to the experts. I find it difficult to sometimes even phrase the question to properly Google!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is too difficult to give a detailed answer to your question. Information Security is an enormous subject.

Wherever possible you should rely on existing solutions and implementations. E.g. can you use OAuth or OpenID so that your app never needs to deal with passwords?  Can you use the local authentication framework if you just want to secure local access to the app?

The short answer to your question "Can you use `.hash`?" is **NO**

`.hash` is used to create a hash for an object that can be used to aid lookup in collections like dictionaries and sets.

It is computationally simple so that it can be calculated quickly. It does not go to any lengths to prevent hash collisions (two different objects hashing to the same value).  It has these characteristics because it is expected that the function will be used a lot (each access to a dictionary for example) and collisions don't really matter; in-memory collections are quite small and collisions can be handled easily.

This is the opposite of what you want in a cryptographic password hash, such as [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt):

- you want the hash function to be relatively slow and computationally expensive to slow brute force attacks; passwords are not hashed/checked very often so this doesn't matter in the normal course of things
- You don't want collisions; a collision will result in an incorrect password being accepted as correct

Comment: Using an existing solution like OAuth is a particularly good suggestion.